# Nested routing in React router 4

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have a component, App component, NewHome Component and Results component.

My route in component App looks like

```
 <Route exact path="/" component={NewHome} />
 <Route path="flights/search/roundtrip" component={Results} />
```

NewHome Routes look like

```
<Route path="/flights" component={FlightSearch} />
<Route path="/hotels" component={HotelSearch} />
```

Results component is class based react component

Only App component gets render, but component inside, I can see null in react devtools and Ui only has the part of App not part of results

```
<Route path="flights/search/roundtrip" component={Results}>
null
<Route />
```

Ideally, it should work, but I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong here. Any pointers or suggetions will be helpful. What can be the probable reasons for this kind of behaviour

This is the code where i am doing reactdom.render in index.js file

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <Route path="/" component={App} />
        {/* {routes} */}
      </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  )
```

Note: full url is something like this

> http://localhost:3001/flights/search/roundtrip?search_type=roundtrip&origin=BLR&destination=MAA&travel_date=2018-01-29&return_date=2018-02-13&class_type=ECONOMY&adult_count=1&child_count=0&residentof_india=true&infant_count=0&originAndDestinationSwapped=false&activeIndexMulticity=0

Comment: so what you are saying is  NewHome Routes is not working?

Comment: basically flights/search/roundtrip route is not working

Comment: and its coming here  <Route path="flights/search/roundtrip" component={Results} /> ?

Comment: yes, its is coming her. you are rright

Comment: you have exported Results as Default right? and imported correctly?

Comment: Yes, one more thing Results is a connected component

Comment: can you wrap your component in withRouter HOC imported from  react-router-dom? like this 
export default withRouter(Results);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164076/discussion-between-sujit-warrier-and-stack26).

Answer (score 0):

`NewHome` gets a `match` prop. With that, simply contact its url with nested routes you might need.

NewHome component:

```
render() {
  const { match } = this.props

  return (
    <div>
      <Route path={`${match.url}/flights`} component={FlightSearch} />
      <Route path={`${match.url}/hotels`} component={HotelSearch} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: dont forget to wrap your components in the withRouter HOC for this to work.

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier: @stack26 mentioned that his `App` component renders both `NewHome` and `Results` routes. So I'm assuming that `NewHome` doesn't need to be wrapped in `withRouter` since `App` must be already wrapped with `Router` or `Switch` :)

Comment: @mersocarlin : /hotels has a different hirearchy.  when i ad your change /flight route breaks , give me the following error
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`.

Comment: @mersocarlin: Note that every thing renders in my  current code structure except /flights/search/roundtrip . the following route content doesnot get rendered

Comment: @stack26 the error you have (Invalid prop component of type object...) is due to wrong import from `FlightSearch`.

Comment: import are same as before. i am actually moving my project form react router 2 .xto react router 4. FlightSearch is a stateless component and have export default FlightSearch in the end. importing it like import FlightSearch from "dumbComponents/Desktop/Flights/Search"

Comment: @stack26 same with `HotelSearch`?

Comment: @mersocarlin Yes !!

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you forgot a '/' in your route.

try

```
  <Route path="/flights/search/roundtrip" component={Results} />
```

instead of

```
   <Route path="flights/search/roundtrip" component={Results} />
```

try exporting your component after wrapping your component in  withRouter HOC

```
import { withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
```

and export the component as follows

```
export default withRouter(Results);
```

Comment: Failed prop type: Invalid prop component of type object supplied to Route, expected function

Comment: <Route path="/flights/search/roundtrip" component={Results} /> using it like this and used withRouter as export default withRouter(Container(Results)) but getting error client.js:1097 Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `Route`.

Comment: what is this Router(Container(Results))  ? shouldnt it be Router(Connect(Results)) or is Container an HOC?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164077/discussion-between-stack26-and-sujit-warrier).

Answer (score -1):

I have found out the issue, in my app i was importing Route from react-router-dom. Its available in react-router. May be a correct error message would have helped :) Thanks @sujit and @mersocarlin for giving valuable inputs.